# How do I write email data to an NFC tags?

Tags: android, email, nfc, ndef

I tried the following code for writing text data, and it's a work fine

```
NdefRecord mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", remainingString.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
ndef.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(mimeRecord));
```

This for launch application.

```
NdefRecord[] records = {NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.demo.abc"),
```

but i dont understand how to write email content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**for write email data**

```
NdefRecord mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createUri("mailto:" + "abc@gmail.com" + "?body=" + "your email message");
ndef.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(mimeRecord));
```

***Understand carefully***

```
NdefRecord.createUri("mailto:" + "abc@gmail.com")
```

**write if you want to write only receiver email id into NFC tag**

```
NdefRecord.createUri("mailto:" + "abc@gmail.com" + "?body=" + "your email message")
```

**write if you want to write receiver email id and message into NFC tag**

```
NdefRecord mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createUri("mailto:" + "abc@gmail.com" + "?subject=" + "your email subject" + "&body=" + "your email message")
```

**write if you want to write receiver email id, email subject and message into NFC tag**

Answer (score 0):

you could write two records , the first one is `uri_record` and second one is `text_record`

you could write in the first one the email address and in second one the text.

```
NdefRecord uri_record = NdefRecord.createUri("https://abc.defg.hi");
String text = "Here is the email content";

NdefRecord text_record= NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", text.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
NdefRecord[] records = {uri_record , text_record};
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
ndef.connect();
ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
ndef.close();
```